# Filter push-down to storage layer in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I recently watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UueWySREWvk&feature=youtu.be) on BigQuery where execution plans are shown that have a READ stage that starts with a FILTER, which means the filter was pushed down to the storage layer.

Is that notation still used in BQ nowadays? I have written various queries that do simple filters and they all end up with an initial stage that simply says READ ... WHERE

I was wondering if there had been a change in the way execution plans are shown or what determines if a filter can be pushed down. The documentation is not helpful for this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first stage has READ immediately followed by WHERE, then the filter is being pushed down to the storage layer. This is most relevant for queries that filter on a partitioning or clustering column, but even outside of that, you'll still see a performance benefit by having the WHERE clause applied where the read happens.

Comment: So if it cannot be pushed down to the storage layer, how would that show up?

Comment: It would appear in a later stage, such as if you write a filter on a column from the right side of a left outer join (which prevents filter push down since the outer join can introduce NULL values).